# EXC_BAD_ACCESS error in getting sprite position when mousejoint is released

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, exc-bad-access, box2d-iphone

I am trying to get the exact position of a sprite at the time a mousejoint moving the sprite is released (even though the sprite might still be moving) and display it. I am using Cocos2d and Box2d. Below is the code ccTouchesEnded method.

ccTouchesEnded:

```
- (void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

if (mouseJoint)
{
    b2Fixture *fixture;
    CCSprite *mySprite = (CCSprite *) fixture->GetUserData();
    NSInteger attachedSprite = mySprite.tag;
    if (attachedSprite == 1) {
        CGPoint spritePosition = mySprite.position;

        CCLOG(@"the sprite position is x:%0.2f, y:%0.2f", spritePosition.x, spritePosition.y);
        }
    world->DestroyJoint(mouseJoint);
    mouseJoint = NULL;
}
}
```

I keep getting the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error pointing to the line:

```
CCSprite *mySprite = (CCSprite *) fixture->GetUserData();
```

I am not really sure what's wrong. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that error because fixture has not been initialized, check out this
[tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/606/how-to-use-box2d-for-just-collision-detection-with-cocos2d-iphone), how he loop over all the world elements

```
for(b2Body *b = _world->GetBodyList(); b; b=b->GetNext()) {
    if (b->GetUserData() != NULL) {
        CCSprite *curSprite = (CCSprite *)b->GetUserData();
...
    }
}
```

you have to assign something to the fixture before do the GetUserData()

Comment: Thanks. I've made the changes but I the CCLOG is not appearing. Here's the new ccTouchesEnded code:

Comment: `- (void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
   if (mouseJoint) 
    {
        for(b2Body *b = world->GetBodyList(); b; b=b->GetNext()) {
            if (b->GetUserData() != NULL) {
                CCSprite *mySprite = (CCSprite *)b->GetUserData();
                if (mySprite.tag == 1) {
                    CGPoint spritePosition = mySprite.position;
                    CCLOG(@"the sprite position is x:%0.2f, y:%0.2f", spritePosition.x, spritePosition.y); }
            }
        }        
        world->DestroyJoint(mouseJoint);
        mouseJoint = NULL;
    }  
}`

Comment: :please take a look at this follow up [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11883147/cclog-not-displaying)